# Adding Filtering in an array objects duplicated in existing method

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I have the following array

```
 [{ id: 1,
    type: 'video',
    image: null,
    url: 'https://www.youtube.com/1'
  },
  { id: 2,
    type: 'video',
    image: null,
    url: 'https://www.youtube.com/2' 
  },
  { id: 3,
    type: 'image',
    image: 'https://example-1.url.webp'
  },
  { id: 4,
    type: 'image',
    image: 'https://example-2.url.jpg',
  },
  { id: 5,
    type: 'video',
    image: 'https://www.youtube.com/2',
  }   
]
```

I am already filtering all the items who are not **webp** format and the **image** is `null`

```
  const galleryFilter = gallery.filter(
    (item) => item?.image?.indexOf("webp") === -1 || item?.image === null
  );
```

As you can see there are 2 `items` (id **2** and id **5** ) with the same url, how can i also filter the item duplicated with the same url in the `galleryFilter` method ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Not unfortunately

Comment: append another filter logic

Comment: @Koala7 What do you mean? Your question is an exact duplicate. You want to filter by "image" instead of "name", but that's it. The linked question has 75 answers. How can this not help you?

Comment: Ok so why you are making me this question if you contest my answer

Comment: Why not? It's just another condition in the filter--what specific issue are you having?

Comment: I have made a really detailed question with code example

Comment: I'm asking why the other question doesn't answer the additional filter requirement-what specifically isn't understood? You have one of your filter conditions working; it can be combined with the dupe question and answers to fulfill your requirements. Perhaps if you post your attempt it will become more clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can append another filter function to filter by image url, (I have added another object into your data set `id: 6`)

```js
var gallery =  [{ id: 1,
    type: 'video',
    image: null,
    url: 'https://www.youtube.com/1'
  },
  { id: 2,
    type: 'video',
    image: null,
    url: 'https://www.youtube.com/2' 
  },
  { id: 3,
    type: 'image',
    image: 'https://example-1.url.webp'
  },
  { id: 4,
    type: 'image',
    image: 'https://example-2.url.jpg',
  },
  { id: 5,
    type: 'video',
    image: 'https://www.youtube.com/2',
  },
  { id: 6,
    type: 'video',
    image: 'https://www.youtube.com/2',
  }
];

var galleryFilter = gallery.filter( (item) => item?.image?.indexOf("webp") === -1 || item?.image !== null ).filter((item, i, arr) => i == arr.findIndex(e => e.image == item.image));

console.log(galleryFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and keep track of images with `Set`

```js
const gallery = [
  { id: 1, type: "video", image: null, url: "https://www.youtube.com/1" },
  { id: 2, type: "video", image: null, url: "https://www.youtube.com/2" },
  { id: 3, type: "image", image: "https://example-1.url.webp" },
  { id: 4, type: "image", image: "https://example-2.url.jpg" },
  { id: 5, type: "video", image: "https://www.youtube.com/2" },
];

const set = new Set();

const galleryFilter = gallery.filter((item) => {
  if (
    (item?.image?.includes("webp") || item?.image === null) &&
    !set.has(item?.image)
  ) {
    set.add(item.image);
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(galleryFilter)
```